# Scrolling in a web page using Selenium and Python for data grabbing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I used webdriver and I faced an error every time I ran my code, here is the error:

```
  in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) 
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: Error: Permission denied to access property "scrollTo" "
```

This is my code:

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: do you wait for the page to load completely?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Re  Ankur Goel: Yes. I run the code in debugging mode in Pycharm and execute line by line and also I faced with this error

Comment: Re DebanjanB: as well as I tell in the subject I want Scrolling in a web page using Selenium and Python for data grabbing. I want to scrolling to the end of the page to load all content of the page and then grab the data.